# How to assign property for BasicDatePicker in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, datepicker

I want to assign property for BasicDateTimePicker

I tried but it's getting null value

Code:

.ascx

```
<%@ Register Assembly="BasicFrame.WebControls.BasicDatePicker" Namespace="BasicFrame.WebControls" TagPrefix="dp" %>

<dp:BasicDatePicker ID="BasicDatePicker4" runat="server"></dp:BasicDatePicker>
```

.ascx.cs

Here I'm maintaing the values

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtUser.Text = Request.Form[txtUser.UniqueID];
  dropCountry.SelectedValue = Request.Form[dropCountry.UniqueID];
  dropEntry.SelectedValue = Request.Form[dropEntry.UniqueID];
  //Here I'm getting "Cannot implicitly conert type string to System.Date"
  BasicDatePicker4.SelectedDate = Request.Form[BasicDatePicker4.UniqueID];
}
```

I tried to assign the property but it's not working

```
    public string ExpiryDate
    {
        get
        {
            return BasicDatePicker4.SelectedDate.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            BasicDatePicker4.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never assign something to ExpiryDate, the setter of the property will only be called when you call

```
ExpiryDate = DateTime.Today
```

also change your setter to use value instead of a hardcoded date, and change the Type of your property to DateTime as the picker only excepts a DateTime

```
public DateTime ExpiryDate
{
    get
    {
        return BasicDatePicker4.SelectedDate;
    }
    set
    {
        BasicDatePicker4.SelectedDate = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but when I call this property in aspx.cs page string expirtyVisa = usercontrol.ExpiryDate.ToShortDateString(); I got result like this format 11/1/0001 how to solve this?

Comment: please mark this question as answered and create a new one regarding your format problems.

Comment: And maybe read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx which is the documentation for that method. There are many ways to format a date, all very well documented

Comment: Sorry for asking again here how to set BasicDatePicker4.SelectedDate = Request.Form[BasicDatePicker4.UniqueID];
}